# Where can I find this html code on the ftp server of my website?

Tags: html, web, ftp

I added an html code a long time ago on my wordpress website (the Facebook button on the left of my [website](http://mamou-mani.com)) and i am having a very hard time locating it on my ftp server.

Is there a way to locate it from my browser or at least know in which folder it could be? Otherwise can I do a search on filezilla for the term "facebook" and look for each file?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there isn't. The location of the root folder is not visible to HTTP clients. Best to get shell access and look from there.

Comment: Thanks @Diodeus. Could I do a search on filezilla for the term "facebook" and look for each file?

Comment: @diodeus: or at least should NOT be visible. I've seen a few webservers where the document root was the file system root. "no one will never see it!"

Comment: @Diodeus what is shell access?

Comment: It's a virtual terminal session.

Answer (score 0):

Since its wordpress, your content is probably somewhere in wp-content/themes/ .

Since your question is about something on the side of your site, look in the sidebar.php file. Though this is theme dependant.